# Как убрать горизонтальные отступы в блоках bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, html

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от отступов между блоками в бутстрап.
Вот ссылка: http://newsgrabber.tk/
Вот я стрелками показал,о каких отступах я говорю. Это стандартные бутстраповские отступы в гриде, как я понимаю...
Мне хотелось чтобы блоки были по вертикали слитны с соседними блоками сверху и снизу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar, .breadcrumb{
   margin-bottom: 0
}
```